# how to do a system pause in java for debugging?

Tags: java

Is there any functionality in Java for pausing the program like `system("PAUSE");` does in C++?

Comment: @Lutz- I guess this: http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html

Comment: SYSTEM("PAUSE") is used in C++, which basically triggers the DOS command pause. You should never use it in C++ (there are better ways to stop execution) :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doing debugging is best done with a debugger, NetBeans (what you seem to be using if I look at other questions you have asked) has one. Just click in the left margin of an editor window to set a breakpoint and run the debugger. Program execution will stop at the breakpoint and you can have a look at the current state of variables, or step through the program line by line.

Comment: I second the debugger.  Learn how to use it and it will make your development life *much* easier.  There are many links on the web.  Here's one to help you get started: Getting Started with Netbeans - http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/tools/netbeans_part1/#debugging

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  There are other reasons besides debugging for pausing application execution when coding a console application.

Comment: I agree with Ted.  For example, if you were profiling the application and wanted to have a chance to start something in the tool, you'd need a pause to do so.

Answer (score 13):

The Short Is Yes, But You Have To Build It Using The Standard Output With `System.out` and Using The `Scanner` Class To Wait For New Line Input ('\n') From Standard Input From The `System.in`

```
public class PauseTest {

     public static void main(String args[]){

          System.out.println("Press Any Key To Continue...");
          new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
     }
}
```

NOTE: I used a direct reference to the `Scanner` Class in `java.util` package, but you could simply add the import `java.util.Scanner;` or `import java.util.*;` Basically the same thing.

Comment: 'any' should be 'the [enter]' ?

Answer (score 2):

You mean like [Thread.sleep()](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html)? Please elaborate if you want further help...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Java very well, but if you want to debug, then you may want to use debugger, and breakpoints for pausing execution.
If you just want to wait for keyboard input, then check out `System.in.read`, or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

There is a cin.get(), or cin.ignore() thing in C++, which basically makes you press the enter key to to exit the program, I know it is cheesy, but it works.
What you could do is setup a scanner with a .nextLine(), like this

```
    import java.util.Scanner;


 public class Example {

public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner pauser = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("!!!Hello World!!!");
    pauser.nextLine();
    }

 }
```

then the user must press enter to exit the program.

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to debug, use a debugger.  Netbeans and Eclipse both have one built in, and I am sure there are others.

If you are trying to get a thread to wait on another thread, use a thread.join().